# Chance JQuery Vertical drop down slider the expand horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been using a JQuery drop down slider for a variety of uses, but I want to set up a menu of sorts in a different direction. Currently the slider drops down vertically as expected. I'm unsure of how to make the slider expand out to the right from the triggering div.

All research on the topic only turns up css style navigation menus.

http://jsfiddle.net/qxfmf2m0/

```
 <script>
function toggleSlides(){
$('.toggler').click(function(e){
 var id=$(this).attr('id');
 var widgetId=id.substring(id.indexOf('-')+1,id.length);
 $('#'+widgetId).slideToggle();
 $(this).toggleClass('sliderExpanded');
 $('.closeSlider').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide('slow');
        var relatedToggler='toggler-'+$(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+relatedToggler).removeClass('sliderExpanded');
    });
  });
};
$(function(){
  toggleSlides();
});
</script>
```

I appreciate any help or leads you can provide.

As always, thank you!
-BR89

Comment: Are you referring to making an "off-canvas menu"?

Comment: Here is a stupid simple jquery off-canvas menu http://codepen.io/scottb/pen/javhr

Comment: The Off Canvas Menu's animation is actually exactly what I am looking for (with the exception of the media query responsiveness).  Can that panel feature be replicated in say 4 or 5 divs on a page?